# How to append query results using BigQuery Python API

Tags: python, api, google-bigquery, sql-insert

I cannot find a way to append results of my query to a table in BigQuery that already exists and is partitioned by hour.
I have only found this solution: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results.

```py
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id)

sql = """SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.art_n=table2.artn"""

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
query_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
```

But providing a destination table to `bigquery.QueryJobConfig` overwrites it, and I did not find that `bigquery.QueryJobConfig` would have an option to specify `if_exists` or something. As far as I understand, I need to apply `job.insert` to query results, but I do not understand how.

I also did not find any good advice around, maybe someone can point me to it?

Just in case, my real query is huge and I load it from a separate JSON file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your `job_config`, you need to set the `write_disposition` to `WRITE_APPEND`:

```
[..]
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    allow_large_results=True, 
    destination=table_id, 
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND'
)
[..]
```

See [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html?highlight=queryjobconfig#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.write_disposition).

Answer (score 1):

You can add below lines to append data into existing table:

```
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
```

Complete Code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination="myproject.mydataset.target_table")
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'   
sql = """SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.art_n=table2.artn"""
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
query_job.result()
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter that you were looking for is called [write_disposition](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.write_disposition). You want to use WRITE_APPEND to append to a table.